# Create a Custom error response on empty route parameter(s)

Tags: c#, .net, routes

- using .net 8 and the default .net core web api template
- i cannot change the route path so no altering routes to queries
- the requests will come in as below (i gave 3 examples of requests)

I am trying to get a custom error rather then the usual 404 not found whenever the url has an empty route parameter.

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("{routeParam1}/{routeParam2}/path/{routeParam3}", Name = "XYZ")]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> XYZ(
                    [FromRoute] string routeParam1, 
                    [FromRoute] string routeParam2, 
                    [FromRoute] string routeParam3,
                    [FromQuery] string queryParam1, 
                    [FromQuery] string queryParam2, 
                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      return new ObjectResult("ok") { StatusCode = 200 };
  }
```

result should be

```
 Request: /abc/xyz//routeParam2/path/routeParam3?queryParam1=p1&queryParam2=p2
 Response: 422
 {
    "customCode": "1111",
    "warning": "routeParam1 is required."
 }



 Request: /abc/xyz/routeParam1//path/routeParam3?queryParam1=p1&queryParam2=p2
 Response: 422
 {
    "customCode": "2222",
    "warning": "routeParam2 is required."
 }


 Request: /abc/xyz/routeParam1/routeParam2/path/?queryParam1=p1&queryParam2=p2
 Response: 422
 {
    "customCode": "3333",
    "warning": "routeParam3 is required."
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think i have something let me know if there's a better way

in program /startup (you may need to instal SYstem.Security.Permissions nuget package)

```
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseMiddleware<ValidateRouteParametersMiddleware>();
```

---

```
public class ValidateRouteParametersMiddleware 
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  private static Regex _regexPattern = new Regex(".*\\/xyz\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)\\/path\\/([^\\/]*)\\/?"); 

public ValidateRouteParametersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    _next = next;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path;
    var match = _regexPattern.Match(requestPath);
    // Check if the request path matches the targeted endpoint
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string value1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string value2 = match.Groups[2].Value;
        string value3 = match.Groups[3].Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value1))
        {
            await HandleError(context, "1111", "routeParam1 is required.");
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value2))
        {
            await HandleError(context, "2222", "routeParam2 is required.");
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value3))
        {
            await HandleError(context, "3333", "routeParam3 is required.");
            return;
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}

private async Task HandleError(HttpContext context, string customCode, string warning)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 422;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { customCode, warning }));
}
```

}